# Can you use the "Inline Install" feature for Google Apps Marketplace listings?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store

I have an app in the Google Apps Marketplace via the Chorme Web Store.

On the Edit Listing page is an option for [Inline Install](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation).

I have followed the instructions, but when I click the link, I get an error in the console "Uncaught Chrome Web Store installations can only be initated by a user gesture.".

This is misleading, as it *is* triggered by a user gesture.

I have tried various different things such as providing the URL as the first argument to the install method, and have stepped through the code. Everything looks okay my end - I am now thinking that maybe this feature is not compatible with Google Apps Marketplace listings?

For clarity, here is my code:

*Link*

```
<link rel="chrome-webstore-item"
   href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/[listingId]">
```

*Javascript:*

```
document.getElementById('btnTestInline').addEventListener('click', function() {
    chrome.webstore.install();
});
```

*HTML:*

```
<button id="btnTestInline">Add to Chrome</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Also Google are removing the inline installation also any kind of apps and extensions.

> As of 06/12/2018, inline installation is deprecated.

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation